# need the javasript solution for on button client click funtion call button on click method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have button where I used java script confirm alert display on button client-click  method.
on same if output is true then I have to call button on-click method else not.
please help.

```
    function myFunction() {
        var txt;
        var r = confirm("Press a button!");
        if (r == true) {
            txt = "You pressed OK!";
            __doPostBack('OnClick', 'btnUploadCalender');
        } else {
            txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById("hID").innerHTML = txt;
    }
```

Comment: Why you aren't using ajax ? move your business logic to a service layer (or just a simple method) then call this service method  when click on button and when ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<script>
function myFunction(canNotProceed) {
    if (canNotProceed) {
        var txt;
        var r = confirm("Press a button!");
        if (r == true) {
            txt = "You pressed OK!";
            document.getElementById("hID").innerHTML = txt;
            myFunction(false);
        } else {
            txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
            document.getElementById("hID").innerHTML = txt;
            return false;
        }
            
    } else {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = 'btnDelete';
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = '';
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUploadCalender" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUploadCalender_Click" OnClientClick="return myFunction(true);" />
```

Comment: can we give the message from resource file in confirm pop up box.

Comment: Read message from resource file in code behind and assign to a public variable and name it to **myMessage**, then assign to a javascript variable like this:
```
<script>
let message = <%=myMessage%>
<script>
```
Now you can use **message** variable in popup

Comment: Hi @pooja, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course there is no obligation to do this. Have a good day. :)